# How to select individual items in a table view row?

Tags: iphone

What's the best way to create a table view with thumbnails (like the iPhone Photos app)?

The problem I have is the selection part. How do I get information about the selected thumbnail of a selected row? A delegate method like:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atPoint:(CGPoint)touchedPointInCell
```

...would have made it easy. But how do I do this when I don't get the x or column of a table view selection?

Thanks in advance,

/ Påhl

Comment: Did you try with custom UITableViewCell and put a UIButton inside your cell?

Comment: I am using custom UITableViewCell:s. I haven't tried using UIButtons, yet. But I planned on trying to use UIImageViews if there is no simple answer. I guess I need to tag the views with the row or some id to get the correct selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of views use  the buttons so that you can get its click event. And give some unique tag to each of the button so that you can get which button os clicked.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Tagging the buttons in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: delegate method and checking the tag in the click event of the button.

Answer (score 0):

i would use UIScrollView

Comment: If I recall correctly, Apple is using a table view in the Photos app and in many other apps as well. I want to use a table view to minimize memory use by only allocating views for the visible thumbnails.

Comment: in wwdc examles they using UIScrollView for scroll like in photo app

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the wwdc session (104 - Designing Apps with Scroll Views). I did't go that session this year, but I just watched the video. It's a very good session with sample code to do a slide show of images and I would also use a UIScrollView for that. But my "problem" was the thumbnail view where you select the image to view in the slide show. I will try using tagged UIButton:s in the cell as vodkhang and Suriya suggested. I'm still not sure if Apple is using UITableView or UIScrollView in the tumbnail view of the Photos app. Both would work but UITableView seems easier.